# Convert a List (long) into List(String ) in Grails2.4.3 (Groovy)

Tags: grails, groovy

Post call gives data in the form of `List<Long>` and now I have to convert it into `List<String>`, so I used this approach for it:

```
deleteAvailablity.startDate.each {
   startDateList.add(it.toString())
}
deleteAvailablity.startDate = startDateList
```

Is there any better approach than this?

Comment: could you please accept answer that suits your needs best?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`collect`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
def listOfLongs = [0L, 1L, 2L]
def listOfStrings = listOfLongs.collect { it.toString() }

assert listOfStrings == ["0", "1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [Spread Operator](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_spread_operator)

This simple construct should do the job:

```
assert [1l, 2l, 3l]*.toString() == ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: The spread operator is the better option here since it does the same thing as `collect` when calling a method or retrieving a property from every instance, and it's less verbose.